# Virtualize consumer-nvidia/gforce3060 on debian

Tags: gpu-passthrough

Is there a way to virtualize my consumer grade gpu on debian to allow passthorough to

- one VM or ideally
- multiple VMs

as you can do with a CPU?

I cannot imagine there is still no trick/workaround in 2023 to virtualize a GPU. Does someone have any tricks up his sleeves?

My system runs on AMD-CPU and unfortunately NVIDIA Geforce 3060. I think the tricky part would be getting the host-OS (Debian) up and running without the display if nvidia is blacklisted, and AMD-CPU has no GPU, but I could add another cheap graphics card as a workaround.